# select from 3 tables with null values

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

- ***Users***
     COLUMNS   User Name, USER ID
- ***Groups*** 
      COLUMNS   Group Name,Group Id
- ***Users_Group***
      COLUMNS   User ID, Group ID

the User group contains the relation between Users and groups.

I want to select from users and groups to get user names and group names togother. 
But I want also to get the users who dont have group where the return value of group name will be null

How to create such SQL in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `left join` as

```
select 
u.username,
g.group_name
from users u 
left join users_group ug on ug.user_id = u.user_id
left join groups g on g.group_id = ug.group_id
```

Comment: Thanx and Sorry cant vote for you, I have only 6 reputation I need 15 to vote

Comment: Thats fine you can always accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.username,
        g.groupname 
from users u
left join user_group ug on u.userid=ug.userid
left join groups g on g.groupid=ug.groupid
```

Comment: GROUPS table dosn't contain the USER ID